# Cannot read property 'getIn' of undefined in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13, draftjs

Iam facing the error "Cannot read property 'getIn' of undefined" when running my code. Does anyone know how to fix this.

How to reproduce:
just write "aa"

this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState } from "draft-js";
import "draft-js/dist/Draft.css";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function MyEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(() =>
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  const editor = React.useRef(null);
  function focusEditor() {
    editor.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
      </Head>
      <div
        style={{ border: "1px solid black", minHeight: "6em", cursor: "text" }}
        onClick={focusEditor}
      >
        <Editor
          ref={editor}
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={setEditorState}
          placeholder="Write something!"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, you can try my way

```
//just use dynamic import 
const Editor = dynamic(() => import("draft-js").then((mod) => mod.Editor), {
  ssr: false,
});
```